# Wait for ngrx state to be populated in async route guard

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

My route guard needs to wait for state to be populated, but I'm only ever getting the first value, which is of course, `null`

```
export class Guard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select<MyState>('mystate').map(state => {
      if (state && state.thing) {
        this.router.navigate(['/path']);
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

How can I force the guard to wait for the state to be populated?

---

## [update 1]

If I employ the `.skipWhile()` pattern:

```
return this.store
           .select<MyState>('mystate')
           .skipWhile(mystate => {
             if (mystate && mystate.thing) {
               return false;
             }

             console.log('here');

             return true; // <- shouldn't this cause it to keep going?
           })
           .do(mystate => {
             if (mystate.thing.condition) {
               this.router.navigate(['/path']);
             }
           })
           .mapTo(true);
```

`.do(...)` is never evaluated, and `'here'` is only logged once. What am I missing?

---

## [update 2]

What was missing was the call to `.dispatch()` to load my state in the first place. I have a nested module structure, and the container component this guard was placed on was where `.dispatch()` lived. Of course, the guard, prevented the component from initializing, and therefore my state was never populated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [skipWhile](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skipWhile) operator to skip the `null` value. That way the stream would only emit when the state is populated.

```ts
return this.store.select<MyState>('mystate')
  .skipWhile(state => !state || !state.thing)
  // at this point, you're guaranteed that `state` is populated
  .do(() => this.router.navigate(['/path']))
  .mapTo(true);
```

Here's a JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/lupicepoyo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Interesting. If I include the or statement, `do` never fires, but if I leave it off, it does.

Comment: What do you mean by the "or statement": `!state || !state.thing`?

Comment: Correct: `!state || !state.thing`

Comment: I see. I modelled my code after the initial example, some adaptations might be required. The idea is that the `skipWhile()` expression should evaluate to `true` as long you consider your state NOT populated.

Comment: Hmm. I can't seem to get it to work when checking for the state object plus the state object property... I have a workaround where I'm accessing my service class directly for the observable for the guard. Perhaps I'll just stick with that for now and come back to this pattern when I have some more time. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Well, my workaround wasn't working exactly like I thought it did. The problem that I'm seeing is that I really need to check for `!state && !state.thing`, but when I do that, `.do()` is never called.

Comment: You do have a `subscribe()` somewhere right? ;-) Can you take a look at [this Plunkr](http://jsbin.com/wapiji/3/edit?js,console) please? I have included the `!state || !state.thing` and you can see that it works as expected. (I really think the expression should be `||` not `&&` like you wrote in your last comment.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136626/discussion-between-brandon-and-angularfrance).

Comment: Right now, I have the call to `.subscribe()` in the constuctor of the guard class. I took a look at the Plunker, but the `||` statement still isn't working as expected.

Comment: OMG. I finally figured out what was wrong - because of the route guard, the container component of the routes I'm trying to guard never issues the  dispatch command to load state in the first place. (facepalm)

Comment:  You figured it out, that's what matters.

Comment: Haha. Yes, always. Thanks again for getting me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: The do operator is deprecated and the answer is no longer valid for anyone passing here in 2020